# Using C#'s Computer Principal in Active Directory to fill list box with computers based on User Selection

Tags: c#, active-directory

My C# application communicates with the active directory and is able to provide me when i select a user i can see the groups he is a member of and if i select the group i am able to see the users in the group. Now the new requirement i want to see the computers each user is associated with.

```
private void FillComputers()
      {
          computers.Items.Clear();
          PrincipalContext PrincipalContext1 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
          ComputerPrincipal cp = new ComputerPrincipal(PrincipalContext1);
          PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(cp);
          foreach (var cpn in search.FindAll())
          {
              computers.Items.Add(cpn.SamAccountName);
          } 
      }
```

Gives me all the computers how do i pass the selected user as a parameter to the FillComputers above??? Thanks in Advance for all your suggestions.

For example when i have users and i had to find out the groups they were memebers of i did this

The below fills the listbox with all users:

```
private void filluser()
    {
        // create your domain context
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for any UserPrincipal 
        UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

        // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
        PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

        // find all matches
        foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
        {
            try
            {
                // do whatever here 
                UserPrincipal foundUser = found as UserPrincipal;

                if (foundUser != null)
                {
                    foundUser.IsAccountLockedOut();
                    user.Items.Add(foundUser.GivenName + " " + foundUser.Surname + " " + "[" + foundUser.SamAccountName + "]");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

To Fill another list box with the groups the users were members of I did this

```
private void fillmembersof()
    {

        Groups.Items.Clear();
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        String input = user.Text;
        string username = input.Split(new char[] { '[', ']' })[1];
        // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for any UserPrincipal 
        UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
        if (usr != null)
        {
            foreach (var group in usr.GetGroups())
            {
                Groups.Items.Add(group.Name);
            }
            usr.Dispose();
        }

        ctx.Dispose();
      }
```

Than to fill the above text box based on users selected i did this:

```
        private void user_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

          fillmembersof();
          **FillComputers();** -> i want to be able to do the same for computers the user has access to?????
```

Thanks you in advance for all your valuable suggestions!!!!

Comment: In Active Directory I don't believe that a computer is associated with a particular user. I've never seen a connection between the two.

Comment: @lordjeb How about trying to get the users that have access to the selected computer, so before i wanted a list of computer for each user but could be do the opposite say for each computer has multiple users, now that we have a list of computers can we see the users in them? some of these computers are servers as well.

Comment: On a domain system, any user can use any machine that they have rights to. Once the machine is joined to the domain, if the computer allows "Domain Users" group access, then any user COULD access it. This doesn't mean that they do. To figure out who is actually using a computer, you would have to connect to the computer and figure out if they had a local profile, but even that's not perfect, since those profiles can get removed.